# Can Mailman copy its archive to an email address?

Tags: mailman

I am setting up an email address, which I would like to contain all emails ever sent to a Mailman mailing list. The email receives all email that is sent to the list currently. I would like to also have mailman re-send all of the email in its archives to this email address. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: This is an obvious feature missing from Mailman. Suppose I just subscribed to a mailing list. I'm browsing last month's archives and see something I'd like to reply to. Why can't I just go to the web page and run a command "please re-send one month worth of archives to my e-mail address". Then I can go to my inbox and reply to that message.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a script to import the archives they are stored in mbox format. http://wiki.list.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4030624